# Confused about sklearn’s implementation of OSVM

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, sklearn-pandas

I have recently started experimenting with OneClassSVM ( using Sklearn ) for unsupervised learning and I followed 
[this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html)  .

I apologize for the silly questions  But  I’m a bit confused about two things :

1. Should I train my svm on both regular example case as well as the outliers , or the training is on regular examples only ?
2. Which of labels predicted by the OSVM and represent outliers is it 1 or -1

Once again i apologize for those questions but for some reason i cannot find this documented anyware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this example you reference is about *novelty-detection*, the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#novelty-and-outlier-detection) say:

> novelty detection:
>
> The training data is not polluted by outliers, and we are interested in detecting anomalies in new observations.

Meaning: you should train on regular examples only.

The approach is based on:

> Schölkopf, Bernhard, et al. "Estimating the support of a high-dimensional distribution." Neural computation 13.7 (2001): 1443-1471.

Extract:

> Suppose you are given some data set drawn from an underlying probability distribution P and you want to estimate a “simple” subset S of input space such that the probability that a test point drawn from P lies outside of S equals some a priori specied value between 0 and 1.
>
> We propose a method to approach this problem by trying to estimate a function f that is positive on S and negative on the complement.

The above docs also say:

> Inliers are labeled 1, while outliers are labeled -1.

This can also be seen in your example code, extracted:

```python
# Generate some regular novel observations
X = 0.3 * np.random.randn(20, 2)
X_test = np.r_[X + 2, X - 2]
...
# all regular = inliers (defined above)
y_pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)  
...
# -1 = outlier <-> error as assumed to be inlier
n_error_test = y_pred_test[y_pred_test == -1].size
```